# How to mapping the relations between classes (@ManyToMany) for a table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-annotations

How to mapping the relations between three class @ManyToMany unidirectional for a unique table ?

The relations is like that:

- Project have many Task
- Many Task have many specifcs Activitys (to standard) - for each task have many specifcs activitys
- Task and Activitys are standard into the data base.

So, when I'll create a Project, I'll chose somes Tasks and somes Task's Activitys.

I would to create a table (project_task_activity_map) like that:

```
 project_id     task_id    activity_id
    1            2           3
    1            2           4
    2            1           2
    2            1           1
    2            2           3
    2            3           5
```

How can I map the class Project ?

Reference link:

[See Orders Table](http://www.solarisedesign.co.uk/multiple-tables-with-unique-ids-mysql-joins-and-normalization/)

Comment: Neither your table nor the orders table you have linked to are normalized. In that case it's not easy to create a proper mapping. Do you want that?

Answer (score 1):

I think hierarchy like

Project
   |
  Task
   |
Activity

There is no direct relation between Project & Activity.

Better to create many to many table for Task & Activity, keep Project as master only.
Total 4 tables
- Project
- Task
- Activity
- TaskActivityMapping

Fourth table will be created by Hibernate mapping of Task and Activity via Embadable.

Comment: Good solution, but did you know if have some annotation to maintain only three class ? Like: Project, Task, Activity and Project_Task_Activity_map (this one create with one annotation), tables

Comment: by putting all in one table that will make data redudancy. if its fine with you then OK

Comment: Your awnser is invalid, because create a Hibernate Mapping for Task and Activity via Embadable don't work ! The Embadable is useful only for relations **@OneToMany**, not to **@ManyToMany**.

Comment: Try to find example on google you will get the idea of @ManyToMany, because I have used the same in my project and it is working. Currently, i am bit busy otherwise would put the same code as well.

Comment: I tried and I read the hibernate documentation and this can't work, a id Embadable in relation `@ManyToMany` create one table for each type.
For exemple: At Entity Task&Activity `@ManyToMany` Set<Task> tasks;
`@ManyToMany` Set<Activity> activitys; create a 2 others tables:Task&Activity_activitys, Task&Activity_tasks. You can try and this won't work. Unfortunately.