# HQL - Search id's in one table

Tags: java, sql, hql

How to make a research to get all tasks, activities and phases of one Project, using NamedQuerie?

The schema to create a Project is: 
**One project have many task, task have many activities and activities have many phases.**

So, I create a mediator class, and now I need to search in the ProjectCreate Table all id's  for task, activities and phases who are linked with a Project id.

See my class in below :

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ProjectCreateId.class)
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "ProjectCreate.findTAPByIdProjet",
                query = "") ,
            })

public class ProjectCreate implements Serializable {
/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final String FIND_TAP_BY_ID_PROJET = "ProjetCreate.findTAPByIdProject";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Id 
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_project", nullable = false)
private Project project;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_task", nullable = false)
private Task task;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_activity", nullable = false)
private Activity activity;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_phase", nullable = false)
private Phase phase;
//gets and sets

}
```

I don't have idea how to create this NamedQuerie to get the expected result.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the purpose of `ProjectCreate`?

Comment: @JimmyT. The purpose of `ProjectCreate` is to administer the Project, because when I create a Project, I select many Task, and inside of this Task I select activities... see my explanation in this link: [Explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033461/how-to-mapping-the-relations-between-classes-manytomany-for-a-table) . Do you understand my problem ?

Comment: A project consists of existing tasks and activities?

Comment: @JimmyT. Yes! I have one list of Task, inside each Task I have a List of Activities. When I create a Project, I can chose the Tasks and for each Task I chose specif activities, they are compose my Project. Activities are linked a specif groupes, like: Design, Mechanical Calculation, and, for all activities in the Design group, I have 4 phase (concept, detail, verification,approval), for the Mechanical Calculation I have 2 phase. So, when I create a Phase, I'll create a `new ProjectCreate` for each phase.

Comment: Do you want get all tasks, activities and phases of one project with one query?

Comment: @JimmyT. Yes, to make more efficient my application. It's impossible?

Comment: It is possible but more inefficient than using a query per type.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30510/discussion-between-andriel-and-jimmy-t)

Comment: @JimmyT. How can I make a query using ProjectCreate ? Do you know ? Thank you.